# How can I get both outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, output, document.write

I was running some basic test cases with `document.write()` which deletes all existing HTML, in the head tag. Desired output is obtained only when I place the script in `<body>` tag.

Ran the script in body with success. But script is resulting in issues when used in `<head>` tag.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Output</title>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Text";
      document.write(5 + 6);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="demo">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Touch me</button>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected output is -
Text
11.
But only 11 is visible.

Answer (score 4):

`document.write` will erase everything which you had earlier. Your are initially setting the `innerHTML` of element with id `demo` to `Text`, but then you are using `document.write`, which will completely delete your existing `html` and replace it will `11`. You can append the sum of numbers to the `Text`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const num = 5 + 6;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Text " + num;
  //document.write(5 + 6);

}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Touch me</button>
</p>
```

If you do not have any `html` code, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = `Text ${5+6}`;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Touch me</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the script in `<head>` is not an issue.

> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML

Try appending the content using `innerHTML` attribute itself.

More Info on write :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the string **Text** to the `write function` along with those numbers

```
document.write(`Text ${5+6}`)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Output</title>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.write(`Text ${5+6}`);

    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Touch me</button>
  </p>


</body>

</html>
```